# How to fetch an array of remote documents/objects using Axios sequentially?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I have an array of documents/rows/objects ids (yelp businesses) and I want to use axios to fetch their associated data one by one. I used the following snippet for fetching them but I all get is axios error with code 429 (too many requests) `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 429]`. I used many forms of the following code but same result:

```
export const _fetchBusinessesDetails = async (ids : any[]) => {
  const businesses : Array<string> = [];
  const headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer <token>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  ids.map(async (id : string) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/${id}`, { headers });
    console.log(res.data || res.response.data.message);
    if (res.data) {
      businesses.push(res.data);
    } console.log(res.response.data.message);
  });
  return businesses;
};
```

Error code : `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 429]`

Comment: Note that Array iteration methods like `map()` and `forEach()` do not break on `await`

Comment: What is the better way for making it more 'sequential', any ideas?

Comment: I also used axios.all() way as an alternative, but it seems a design restriction made inside yelp's API.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `for..of` loop, and `await` inside it:

```
export const _fetchBusinessesDetails = async (ids : string[]) => {
  const businesses : Array<string> = [];
  const headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer <token>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  for(const id of ids) {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/${id}`, { headers });
    console.log(res.data || res.response.data.message);
    if (res.data) {
      businesses.push(res.data);
    } 
    console.log(res.response.data.message);
  };
  return businesses;
};
```

The difference is that `for..of` (along with `for`, `for..in`, `for await..of`, `while`, `do..wile`) is a syntactical loop, while the array iterator methods take callbacks.